# How to get AWS Cognito user attributes using AWSMobileClient in iOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Question is very simple: I've added user authentication to iOS app using AWS Cognito and AWS Amplify. I have successfully implemented sign in and sign up, but how to get user attributes such as email, full name or phone number?

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:**

For AWSMobileClient ~> 2.12.0, you can fetch user attributes as follows.

```swift
AWSMobileClient.default().getUserAttributes { (attributes, error) in
     if(error != nil){
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
     }else{
        if let attributesDict = attributes{
           print(attributesDict["email"])
           print(attributesDict["given_name"])
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the [documentation](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/authentication#utility-properties) there are several property helpers for common attributes like username:

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getUsername()
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().isSignedIn()
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getIdentityId()
```

You can also get the JWT token and then pull out any user attributes:

```
AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getTokens().getIdToken().getTokenString()
```

Comment: AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getIdentityId() is returning null value....any idea why am I getting null where the signIn process returned success on response

Answer (score 3):

You can use the getUserAttributes with the following API in the latest SDK version `2.8.x`:

```
public func getUserAttributes(completionHandler: @escaping (([String: String]?, Error?) -> Void))
```

You can find the source code here:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSAuthSDK/Sources/AWSMobileClient/AWSMobileClientExtensions.swift#L532

Answer (score 0):

In case you're looking for the email address specifically, and need to do so potentially offline, this would work for you:

```swift
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().getTokens { (tokens, error) in
    if let error = error { print(error.localizedDescription) }
    if let tokens = tokens {
        let email = tokens.idToken?.claims?["email"] as? String
        //completionHandler(email)... etc.
    }
```

While `AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().getUsername()` would be convenient, it will return the id of a User Pool user even if the User Pool is set to use email as the username. I consider this a bug, but have yet to report it to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I also research it on android (Kotlin).

```
// retrieve username
val username = AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().username
```

When you sign in with "email" and "password", "username" is "email".

On the other hand, when the case of iOS (Swift), "username" is really "username" of cognito User Pool, even if you sign in with "email" and "password".

It is so confusing...